# Count number of elements in a JSON Array, and display the result on Textview - Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I want to count the number of elements I am getting through the JSON array, and display it over the TextView using .settext() method.
I am getting the following JSON ARRAY :

```
   {
     "result":
     [
      {
        "id":"283",
        "fullname":"shyam",
        "contactno":"898888888",
        "collegename":"mjc",
        "emailaddress":"shyamzawar",
        "eventname":"gaming"
      },
      {
        "id":"285",
        "fullname":"ffca",
        "contactno":"8888888888",
        "collegename":"Brihan maharashtra College of Commerce (BMCC)",
        "emailaddress":"shyamzawar@ymail.com",
        "eventname":"FootBall"
      }
     ]
    }
```

Below is my activity :

```
private static final String TAG = "userList";
private List<FeedItem> feedsList;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MyRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private TextView ParticipantsCounts;
int count=0;

private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

private final String url="http://bmcctroika.hol.es/get-data.php";;

private int offSet = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);
    // Initialize recycler view
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ParticipantsCounts= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ParticipantsCount);

    // Downloading data from below url
    new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshitems();
        }
    });
}

private void refreshitems() {
    new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url);
}

public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        Integer result = 0;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            // 200 represents HTTP OK
            if (statusCode == 200)
            {
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                parseResult(response.toString());
                result = 1; // Successful

            } else {
                result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
    {
        // Download complete.
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (result == 1)
        {
            adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(AdminActivity.this, feedsList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else
        {
            Toast.makeText(AdminActivity.this, "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}

private void parseResult(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("result");
        feedsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setTitle(post.optString("fullname"));
            item.setContact(post.optString("contactno"));
            item.setEmail(post.optString("emailaddress"));
            item.setEventname(post.optString("eventname"));
            item.setCollegename(post.optString("collegename"));
            feedsList.add(item);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to get the `lenght` of the `result` `JSONArray`. So in your code, you can get the length of `posts` -- `JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("result");`.
This will give you the number of items in the result array:

```
private void parseResult(String result) {
    try {
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("result");
        int number = posts.length();
        //then to set it to the text view:
        ParticipantsCounts.setText(String.valueOf(number));
        //the rest of your code ...
        feedsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setTitle(post.optString("fullname"));
            item.setContact(post.optString("contactno"));
            item.setEmail(post.optString("emailaddress"));
            item.setEventname(post.optString("eventname"));
            item.setCollegename(post.optString("collegename"));
            feedsList.add(item);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, I am glad it helps. Keep coding.

Comment: Hey, wait, it's giving error while parsing JSON data, the count works well, but now, it is not displaying the parsed data @ishmaelMakitla

Comment: But that's a different problem then (you reject the answer?) - you wanted to know how to display the count/number of items in your JSONArray. In any case, please paste the error that you are getting - or post a separate question with the specific error you need help with.

Comment: if I remove this code
'int number = posts.length();
        //then to set it to the text view:
        ParticipantsCounts.setText(String.valueOf(number));'
I get the parsed data, else I only get the element count

Comment: That is very strange because the two lines are not doing anything to the actual JSONArray object - only getting the count. Please paste the updated code for the `parseResult` function -  so I can see the version of your code and suggest how to correct it.

Comment: Check out that code, and please provide me with a solution @ishmaelMakitla

Comment: Can you move the two lines that I suggested to **below** the `for-loop` and check if you still do not get the parsed data.

Comment: This is very strange. So when you are not getting the parsed data - what is the "count"? For instance, does it show the correct number of items but not the actual data - meaning the for-loop somehow does not get executed?

Comment: It shows the number of count, but not the content.
In the doinbackground() method, its returning result=0, and then toast message "Failed to fetch data!"

Comment: OK, that's a problem with the code in the `doInBackground()` - perhaps an issue with the `HTTP` request because it does not seem to retrieve the data - that's what the  `Failed to fetch data!` is indicating.

Comment: so, is there any solution to this ?

Comment: not working..  getting error  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "result". my array  check this url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users